# Identifying squares of dots with opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I have an image with four squares of points in it, each with four corner points and other, interior points...

What is the best way to identify each as a separate square so I can process it individually as a Mat, or ROI?

They may be tilted, so the sides in 2d might not look equal, but each will have the same number of points, and each can be contained in a 4-sided polygon.

I have this:

http://i58.tinypic.com/wwdw0l.jpg

...and I want to get to this:

http://i59.tinypic.com/2dm9gtl.jpg

many thanks.

c++, visual studio, opencv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First of all, the small blobs should be detected, i.e. through [`cv::SimpleBlobDetector`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_feature_detectors.html#simpleblobdetector) class,
2. Using [`cv::kmeans()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/clustering.html#kmeans) to find centers of blob clusters and to group blobs around the clusters,
3. Finally, [`cv::minAreaRect()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=minarearect#minarearect) will find the rotated rectangle of the minimum area enclosing the clustered 2D point set.

Comment: Thanks! I am running findContours, then cv::moments, then to get the centroid of each contour:

                for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
             {
                 centroids[i] = Point2f(mu[i].m10 / mu[i].m00, mu[i].m01 / mu[i].m00);

                      pointsForSearch.push_back(centroids[i]);
             }


So i have every centre point in the pointsForSearch vector.

Will kmeans give me the centre of each cluster?

Comment: OK, I have the centre points saved in a vector. I am passing it to kmeans like this: (Taken from the opencv example)

`kmeans(pointsForSearch, clusterCount, labels,
  TermCriteria(TermCriteria::EPS + TermCriteria::COUNT, 10, 1.0),
  3, KMEANS_PP_CENTERS, centers);
 
 for (i = 0; i < sampleCount; i++)
 {
  int clusterIdx = labels.at<int>(i);
  Point ipt = points.at<Point2f>(i);
  circle(src, ipt, 2, Scalar(255, 0, 0), 12, 12);

 }`


But it does not compile. What am i screwing up here?

Comment: Try to use this [example](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/kmeans.cpp)

Comment: That is the one i have... It works with the point-generation, but where do i pass it my own vector? 

thanks again for your help.

Comment: The type of `pointsForSearch` can be i.e. `std::vector<cv::Point2f>`, try declare it as that.

Comment: For testing, i have made a new `vector<cv::Point2f> data` and manually add points to it with data.push_back. 
Still the same debug error.

Comment: aahhh wait... SHould I be putting the data in a Mat?

Comment: found it here:
http://answers.opencv.org/question/36751/kmeans-clustering-for-vectorpoint2f-data-structure/

Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Kornel! Find contours, find moments, use kmeans on the centre points as detailed here:

http://answers.opencv.org/question/36751/kmeans-clustering-for-vectorpoint2f-data-structure/

and use a rotatedrect to get the edges.